# Update mysql db structure (tables config + procedures/functions) and preserve data

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for correct automatic way to update MySQL database which is in production and full of data. I also have development db where I add/change some procedures and add/change tables. So, in some moment when I decide that everything is ready for production, I need to update my production database with this new configuration and preserve all data there. I understand that removing some fields may need complex conversions to the new tables config, but most of my changes will extend functionality, or slightly change it.

As I understand the correct way to do this can be:

1. Dump all data from db.
2. Drop everything in the db and create new
   tables/functions/procedures.
3. Restore data to the db with new
   configuration.

Is this the best way, or there is better one to apply new config without data manipulations?

Comment: Do you have a formal data migration tool where you can define, test and replicate alterations to your schema and data? If not, that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

How long is a piece of string? There is no 'correct' way, it always depends on the specific circumstances. Most methods neccessitate taking the production database offline while you are doing it

One better way is to create a new database schema with the new structure and migrate existing data into the new schema.  You then just change the name of the schema your application is connecting to. That way you preserve the old structure and data in case things go wrong. It is called having a back-out plan. Doing it that way allows for thorough testing of the new schema before putting it live. It also minimises down time. The biggest problem is the insert and update of the existing data while the migration is going on.

In most cases when you are just extending functionality then running a series of CREATE and ALTER statements is all you need. Creating new tables/view/procedures will have no effect on the existing ones. Altering the same objects does. Each needs to be evaluated on a case by case basis for potential data corruption and loss. When adding a column to a table for instance you need to think about default values for existing rows. In all cases the order of the changes will be significant. eg: adding a column before altering a procedure that uses it.